# How to estimate correctly this integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality

Let $a, b\in\mathbb{R}^*_+$ and $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that
$$|f(x)|\le e^{ax} \quad\mbox{ for } |x|>b.$$
While solving an exercise I wrote
$$\left\vert\int_0^t f(x) dx\right\vert \le\int_0^t |f(x)| dx\le t e^{at} \quad\mbox{ for } |t|>b.$$

The professor said that I was wrong because I needed to split the integral in this way
$$\int_0^t f(x) dx =\int_0^b f(x) dx+\int_b^t f(x) dx$$
and then evaluate both of them. Similarly works the case $t\le -b$.

Actually I didn't understand what he meant and how to estimate that integral using the splitting he talked about.

Could someone please help me in understanding that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $|f(x)|\leq e^{ax}$ if $|t|>b$ i.e. $t>b$ and $t<-b$, so if you want to estimate the value of the integral using the bound for the function you need to be in an interval of the form $[b,t]$ with $t>b$. For example $$\left\vert\int_0^t f(x) dx\right\vert \le\int_0^t |f(x)| dx\le t e^{at}$$ does not hold for $t=b/2$, because the bound could not be satisfied in $[0,b/2]$.

Comment: Ok, but how to estimate the integral between $0$ and $b$ then?

Comment: You need more information. With the given we cannot conclude nothing in $[0,b]$